# Passing array of arrays via Ajax

Tags: ajax, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pass an array of arrays via an ajax call to my php script.

```
var myArray=$('input#thisIsAnArray').val();

var dataString='passedArray='+myArray;

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "includes/myPhp.php",
     data: dataString,
     success:function(){


               }

});
```

Then in my Php.php:

```
print_r($_POST['passedArray'][0][0]);
```

I get this retarded message:

```
 Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array
```

Which makes no sense because I am using integers to access the array not a string.

The JSON object structure is:

```
0>
 0>
  admin_id: 1
  status: 1
  date: 1366300373
  outcome_id: 1
  rank: 1
 1>
  admin_id: 2
  status: 2
  date: 1366300373
  outcome_id: 5
  rank: 6
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` show?

Comment: SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in

Comment: print_r($_POST[passedArray]) - [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: That’s because you use the string concatenation operator `+` on a more complex data structure, so it gets convert to just the text `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember well that `dataType` in `jQuery.ajax()` is only the **expected response** from the HTTP call. So what you want to do here is to specify the `contentType`.

More information [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Also, I do not really know how PHP parses the data you send, so make sure the `=` works here.

EDIT: would you please explain to me what those numbers `0>`, and `1>` mean? Because as far as I know [JSON](http://www.json.org/) does not look like that at all.

An array in JSON is written that way:

```
[
    "first value": 1,
    "second value": "a string",
    "and so on": 500,
    "note that the last key does not need a comma",
    "and a key does not need to have a value assigned to it"
]
```

An array of arrays is written that way:

```
[
    ["key": "value in an array which itself is contained in an array"],
    ["second array here"],
    ["and last array, without comma"]
]
```

Comment: I have tried the stringify fuction before passing the array and then json_decode in the php script, I just keep getting "object,object"

Comment: I tried adding the content-type to the ajax call but made no difference. How do I provide an outline of the JSON object. The array is an array of arrays. When I do this: print_r(json_decode($_POST['passedArray'], true) .... the output is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: The JSON object you want to send, could you please write it, or part of it if it is too long, in your question (you can do this by clicking `edit` on your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28472/discussion-between-gustave-monod-and-alan-a)